# Mutable reference cells don't work with static members

Tags: f#, ref

I think I understand what's happening here, but I'd really appreciate someone throwing some light on why it's happening.

Basically (and I'm coding on the fly here, to give the simplest possible illustration) I have a class S which, among other things, maintains a symbol table relating names to objects of the class.  So, inside the class I define:

```
static member (names:Map<string,S> ref) = ref Map.empty
```

... and then later on, also in S, I define:

```
member this.addSymbol (table: Map<string,S> ref) (name:string)
    table := (!table).Add(name, this)
    this
```

I call this from elsewhere, thus:

```
ignore (s.addSymbol S.names "newname")
...
```

Inside S.addSymbol I can see the new key/value being added to table, but S.names doesn't get updated.  If, instead, I call addSymbol like this:

```
ignore (
    let tmp = S.names
    s.addSymbol tmp "newName"
)
```

then I can see tmp being updated with the new key/value pair, but S.names still doesn't get updated.

Here's what I think I know: there's nothing wrong with the ref mechanism - that's updating the referent correctly both inside and outside the function.  But there seems to be something odd about the static member - it's like, rather than just handing me the same static ref 'a each time,  it's copying the 'a and then creating a new ref for that.

Have I got this right?  If so, why is it doing it?  And what can I do to make it behave more sensibly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Vandroiy has diagnosed your immediate problem, but here's an additional thought: if you're going to be mutating a collection then it often makes more sense to use the standard .NET mutable collections rather than a reference wrapping an immutable collection which you update in place.  In your case this would mean using a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>` instead of a `Map<_,_> ref`.

Comment: I did consider using a .net collection, but decided against it, partly for architectural reasons (I've got lots of tables which need to stay in sync, so I didn't want to expose the Add method), but also because it felt like a cop-out - I'm just beginning F#, and I'm trying to do things the "proper" way, rather than just reaching for the C#-alike.  I note from the guidance that one should use objects for the big stuff and functions for the fine stuff.  Not sure what my question is, but I think I'm expressing a sense a lack of informed judgement :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The static member `names` is a *property*, not a static value. It is, internally, a function that creates a new map every time it is called.

If the value has to be in the class, use `static let` to define it inside the class. That way, the reference cell is only created once.

```
type S () =
    static let names = ref Map.empty : Map<string, S> ref
    static member Names = names

S.Names := ["Don", S()] |> Map.ofList
S.Names // gives map with one element
```

Oftentimes, the class doesn't expose the reference cell itself, but rather members to read, add, or remove names. Then, `Names` would return `!names` -- or names would be a plain mutable instead of a reference cell -- and other methods like `AddName` would alter the value. If there is no need for such encapsulation, see kvb's comment for how to shorten this example to only one member. (Thanks for the hint!)

---

**Alternative:** Normally, this is a case in which F# modules are used. Just define

```
let names = ref Map.empty : Map<string, S> ref
```

or

```
let mutable names = Map.empty : Map<string, S>
```

in a module, with additional access restrictions or encapsulation as required.

Comment: You could also use an "automatically implemented property": `static member val names : Map<string, S> ref = ref Map.empty`

Comment: Thanks, Vandroiy - that was a very clear explanation.  It's a shame, in your first suggestion, that it needs that extra name.  I think I like the second answer more.  But kvb's answer is probably the most succinct way to achieve what I was trying to do, and I've just learned a lot about what val does, so thanks are due, too, to you.   It does occur to me, though, that given static member makes a new object each time, and val specifically means that the filed is created once, at construction time, that an undecorated static member is a pretty useless thing - unless  I'm missing something?

Comment: @Jules This is a matter of encapsulation. Often, you would have private values to hold the raw data structure, and then members for the allowed operations on them. `Names` could dereference the value, so that it only reads the map, but cannot change it. Then, members like `AddName` could allow certain, well-defined operations. It depends on the desired safety needs or restrictions around the mutable value. (I edited the answer to point at kvb's comment and mention this.)